# How to uniquely identify buttons using Xpath if the elements like 'id', 'class', 'type', 'value' and 'name' are same for all the buttons

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, buttonclick

I have three buttons in my page out of which I need to click two buttons at different points of time. But I'm not able to do this since the xpath and other html elements (`id`, `class`, `type`, `value` and `name`) are same for all these buttons. How can I uniquely identify these buttons for clicking? Note that the buttons are at different location in the same page, and they need to be clicked one after the other.

I have tried like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='submit'])[2]")).click();
```

and was able to click one button. But when I tried with '3' instead of two, nothing happened.
HTML:

```
<document>
<html class="js" lang="en" dir="ltr" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body class="not-front logged-in page-manage-listing-agent no-sidebars tableHeader-processed">
<!-- wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- container -->
<div id="container">
<!-- page_wrapper -->
<div id="page_wrapper">
<!-- page -->
<div id="page">
<!-- page-header -->
<div id="page-header" class="style_float">
<!--end page-header -->
<div class="clear"/>
<!-- main menu -->
<div class="style_main_menu">
<!--end main menu -->
<div class="clear"/>
<div id="subheading" class="style_flow">
<div class="clear"/>
<!-- center -->
<div id="center" class="style_center_content_default">
<!-- content above -->
<div class="style_content_above_wrapper">
<!-- end content above -->
<!-- left side bar -->
<div id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar">
<!--end left side bar -->
<div class="style_content_main_wrapper">
<div id="content-main">
<!-- error message -->
<div class="error-message "/>
<!-- content help -->
<div class="content-help"/>
<div class="clear-block">
<h3 class="style_sub_title"/>
<form id="rmls-manage-agent-listing" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4740/7/Next">
<div>
<h3 class="style_sub_title">Tour Activity Status</h3>
<input id="edit-step" type="hidden" value="8" name="step"/>
<div class="container-inline-date form-item date-clear-block">
<div class="container-inline-date form-item date-clear-block">
<div class="form-submit-button">
<input id="form-k4S3uBJXVTcXq3Ix1Shkjt3nf-62zmYfOpkAslvJ8tQ" type="hidden" value="form-k4S3uBJXVTcXq3Ix1Shkjt3nf-62zmYfOpkAslvJ8tQ" name="form_build_id"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-manage-agent-listing-form-token" type="hidden" value="f18fc36d4d750ae3912d9cc941aa5c72" name="form_token"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-manage-agent-listing" type="hidden" value="rmls_manage_agent_listing" name="form_id"/>
<table class="sticky-header" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 605px; left: 480px; visibility: hidden;">
<table class="statistic_table sticky-enabled sticky-table">
<div id="style_activity_text" class="style_sub_title_two">Premium Placements</div>
<div id="">
<form id="rmls-activity-report-placement-list-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4740/7/Next">
<div>
<div class="placement_save">
<input id="submit" class="form-submit bluebutton" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_div">
<div class="placement_submit_div">
<input id="submit" class="form-submit bluebutton" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>
</div>
<input id="form-8AJLqZQrgw0cybk8XOkWelCk6iaSJK_7G21QiBLdNKg" type="hidden" value="form-8AJLqZQrgw0cybk8XOkWelCk6iaSJK_7G21QiBLdNKg" name="form_build_id"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-list-form-form-token" type="hidden" value="4305d09bc8205b6d0db44711023395c9" name="form_token"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-list-form" type="hidden" value="rmls_activity_report_placement_list_form" name="form_id"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="style_sub_title_two">Custom Placements</div>
<a class="custom-placement-link" href="/%2523">Add New</a>
<div id="activity_report_placement_form_div" style="display:none;">
<form id="rmls-activity-report-placement-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4740/7/Next">
<div>
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="edit-thumb-wrapper" class="form-item">
<input id="edit-placement-listing-id" type="hidden" value="4740" name="placement_listing_id"/>
<input id="submit" class="form-submit bluebutton" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>
<input id="form-edEgxWrM-VMdRs75vREPtHbONXyCmJR4KkZRkRoSU2Y" type="hidden" value="form-edEgxWrM-VMdRs75vREPtHbONXyCmJR4KkZRkRoSU2Y" name="form_build_id"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-form-form-token" type="hidden" value="185635f8c3122f16a07b5b626e7fc473" name="form_token"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-form" type="hidden" value="rmls_activity_report_placement_form" name="form_id"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="">
<form id="rmls-activity-report-custom-placement-list-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4740/7/Next">
<div class="style_sub_title_two">Activity Report Email Recipients</div>
<div class="style_mail_warpper"/>
<div id="">
<form id="rmls-activity-report-receipient-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4740/7/Next">
<div>
<div id="receipient_add-wrapper" class="form-item">
<input id="activity_listing_id" type="hidden" value="4740" name="activity_listing_id"/>
<div class="rmls_activity_report_receipient_overview_div">
<div class="receipient_submit_div">
<input id="send-submit" class="form-submit style_activity_recipient_sent bluebutton" type="submit" value="Send Report Now" name="op"/>
<input id="submit" class="form-submit style_activity_recipient bluebutton" type="submit" value="Save" name="op"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="activity_report">Top 10 Referrers:</div>
<table class="referrer_table">
</div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="dialog-manage-listing"/>
</div>
<!-- content main -->
<!-- right side bar -->
<!-- end right side bar -->
</div>
<!-- style_content_main_wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- center -->
<div class="clear"/>
<div id="footer">
</div>
<!--end page -->
</div>
<!--end page_wrapper -->
<div id="dialog"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!-- var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-37131766-1"]);_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);(function() {var ga = document.createElement("script");ga.type = "text/javascript";ga.async = true;ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})(); //--><!]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!-- jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "CToolsAJAX": { "scripts": { "/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.min.js": true, "/misc/drupal.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/blockui/jquery.blockUI.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/blockui/blockui.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/block_edit/block_edit.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/google_analytics/googleanalytics.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/superfish.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.core.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.dialog.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.draggable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.droppable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.sortable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/js/rmls.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/clippy/jquery.clippy.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.datepicker.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/lib/jquery.timeentry.pack.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/date_popup.js": true, "/misc/tableheader.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.form.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/ctools/js/ajax-responder.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.resizable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/dialog/dialog.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls_order_verification/custom.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls_order_verification/modal-window.min.js": true }, "css": { "/modules/node/node.css": true, "/modules/system/defaults.css": true, "/modules/system/system.css": true, "/modules/system/system-menus.css": true, "/modules/user/user.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/block_edit/block_edit.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/cck/theme/content-module.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/jquery.timeentry.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/filefield/filefield.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus_default.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/themes/default/ui.all.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/themes/default/ui.datepicker.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/uc_order.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_product/uc_product.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_store/uc_store.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/cck/modules/fieldgroup/fieldgroup.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/rmls.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/style.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/grid.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/order_verification.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls_order_verification/modal-window.css": true } } }); //--><!]]> </script>
</div>
<!--end container -->
</div>
<!--end wrapper -->
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"61afc6e03f","applicationID":"10285903","transactionName":"ZwQAMUZYW0QAAkZaDF5OIwZAUFpZThNfXxBvDAMLVV5QaAAGV10Xbw0LFkBQW1A+B11BDm8WEARESVBF","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":8543,"atts":"S0MDRw5CSEo=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is little bit tricky but please do it like below it will work
before my answer please not why in first case it worked for you

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='submit'])[2]")).click();
// cause in this case you were passing valid index value
```

but when you pass index 3 it does nothing **cause as per your question description you have only 3 buttons on your webpage with same attribute values** so in java the indexing starts form **ZERO not form ONE** so valid index values are 0,1 and 2 only not 3,hence it not worked for you ,now below is the answer

```
// first take each button inside the list 
List<WebElement> myButton = driver.findElements(By.name("submit"));
System.out.println("Size of the button the webpage is : " + myButton.size());
// now you can click button on the basis of index like below

myButton.get(0).click(); // for the first button
//myButton.get(1).click(); // for the second button
//myButton.get(2).click(); // for the third button
```

Also by looking at your source code i can identify the buttons with unique xpath as well plz do it like below

```
// first button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='placement_save']/input")).click();
// second button 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='placement_submit_div']/input")).click();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also find you buttons using following cssSelectors:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".placement_save #submit"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".placement_submit_div #submit"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#edit-placement-listing-id #submit"));
```

If you're looking for a really good guide for css and xpath selectors I highly recommend you [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the suggestions.
I tried like this and it worked for me:
For the first button, I gave like this: 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='submit'])[2]")).click();

And for the second button, I gave like this:
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'form-submit style_activity_recipient bluebutton')]")).click();